# StructureMap error resolving Open Generic dependency

Tags: structuremap, open-generics

So I've wired up my open generic plugin in StructureMap like so

```
scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

But still get the dreaded

> No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily KharaSoft.Utils.IRepository`1[[KharaSoft.App.Core.DomainObject, KharaSoft.App.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]

I debug after the Container is initialized and see that it does indeed have an instance of RepositoryBase<> registered so it knows what I want done, but it won't close it for me. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Looking closer, it looks like it isn't picking up the actual type for some reason. Under the pluginfamily, the FullName of IRepository<> is listed as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure if this is the "best" way but this is what I found that works. I had to explicitly register the open implementation of the plugin like this:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(
  x =>
    {
      x.Scan(scan =>
        {
          scan.Assembly(typeof (IRepository<>).Assembly);
          scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
      x.For(typeof (IRepository<>)).Use(typeof (RepositoryBase<>));
      x.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<MyDataContext>();
    });
return ObjectFactory.Container;
```

See I didn't want to close the generic directly in all cases. So now my MVC controller can take a dependency like so

```
public PlayerController(IRepository<Player> players)
{
  Players = players;
}
```

And StructureMap will close the dependency with an instance of RepositoryBase

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to workout without seeing the full Scan code or your project layout. There are a few default steps I normally go through when I have this issue.

Ensure you have

```
scan.WithDefaultConventions()
```

Ensure that the assembly containing the Repository classes is included in the scan:

```
x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(UserRepository));
```

Ensure that you have the correct implementations in place:

```
IRepository<User>
```

has matching

```
Repository<User>
```

Hopefully something amongst this advice might help you find the issue.

Comment: I think I may have it...testing out solution now.